# Questions about my memory problem for my soundboard android app (E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -19))

Tags: java, android

i have buttons to play sounds, they all works individually, after 14+ uses they dont work anymore if i doesn't restart the app

already tried to mediaplayer.realease after each use, doesnt work, think it is a memory problem dont know how do deal with it

```
MediaPlayer SonDeadliest
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       boutonDeadliest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                SonDeadliest = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.themostdeadliestganginuganda);
                SonDeadliest.start();
                fin(SonDeadliest);
            }
        });
 public void fin(MediaPlayer m)
 {
    if(m.isPlaying())
    {

    }
    else 
    {
        m.stop();
        m.release();
    }
}
```

i have like 24 buttons, i'm trying to get an app with everything that works without having to restart the application thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that using MediaPlayer repeatedly in this way can be misleading:

SonDeadliest = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.themostdeadliestganginuganda);
                SonDeadliest.start();

It will consume unnecessary resources.
For a better understanding I suggest that you read this [post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/deep-dive-mediaplayer-best-practices-feb4d15a66f5). It is written using Kotlin but with a little of kotlin study you can understand.

Here is a implementation in Java, trying to use your scenario:

```
MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer;
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //Media Player setup
        myMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        myMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
        myMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.reset();
            }
        });

        //Buttons
        Button button1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button_record1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playSound(R.raw.record1);
            }
        });
        Button button2 = view.findViewById(R.id.button_record2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playSound(R.raw.record2);
            }
        });
    }

    void playSound(int rawResId) {
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(rawResId);
            if (afd != null) {
                myMediaPlayer.reset();
                myMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                myMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("MediaPLayer", "playSound exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The code can be improved, but my intention here was just to facilitate the comprehension. I'm using only 2 buttons for simplification. But I suggest you to consider using better solutions instead of creating a listener to each one of the 24 buttons. (Take a look on DataBinding, passing the resource as reference).

Comment: thank you !!! it works, i will try to improve my code but some things arent clear for me, i already tried to .reset() after each sound but nothing changed so i dont know exactly how your solution works. thanks you again, i was stuck on this for 2 days :)